# Windows Live Writer: surrounding selected text with a tag?

Tags: formatting, windows-live-writer

When using Windows Live Writer, I'd like to be able to select text and press a key combination to surround it with a given tags (like Ctrl-B surrounds it with `<b>` tags). The one I specifically want to do is either `<code>` or `<pre>`. Is there some way to configure this?

Answer (score 2):

Did you try [text template plugin](http://wlwtexttemplate.codeplex.com/)? It may be the solution you are looking for...